# Uncaught Error: OpenTok Annotation Widget requires an OpenTok Solution

Tags: javascript, annotations, opentok

I am implementing opentok annotation using this code mentioned below and getting this error

**Uncaught Error: OpenTok Annotation Widget requires an OpenTok Solution**

```js
 
toolbar = new OTSolution.Annotations.Toolbar({
  session: session,
  container: document.getElementById('streams'),
  // colors: palette,
  items: [ // Menu item configuration
      {
          id: 'OT_pen',
          title: 'Pen',
          icon: 'image/draw39.png',
          selectedIcon: 'image/draw39-gray.png'
      },
  ]
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/opentok-annotation@2.0.59/dist/opentok-annotation.min.js">
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just confirming, are you using the annotation accelerator pack with the other accelerator packs? They were built to be used in tandem and not alone.

For instance, to use `opentok-annotation` you also need to be using:

- [opentok-accelerator-core](https://www.npmjs.com/package/opentok-accelerator-core)
- [opentok-screen-sharing](https://www.npmjs.com/package/opentok-screen-sharing)